# Resolve a service using Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

Im quite lost here guys, there's this plugin for a gameserver (https://github.com/EvolutionPlugins/Dummy/blob/openmod/Dummy/Services/DummyProvider.cs) which i need to access all the tasks from the DummyProvider service, I have been lead to Autofac Which is what OpenMod(https://github.com/openmod/openmod) uses for IoC, the framework in which the plugin is developed uses.

What Im looking for is to acces objects what the IOC container manages. Any additional information I could provide please let me know

Comment: You should probably check out [this page for tips on asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's not really enough here to understand what you're doing. The title of the question is really vague. You didn't include tags for this "game server" thing which really seems like it's going to play an important part in the answer. Have you [read the Autofac docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) What other research have you done? From where are you trying to resolve services? There's a lot of context you assume we all have, but we don't.

Comment: I understand and apology for my vague question since im not well versed in this. Didnt explain much for this game server since its for a game most likely no one here would recognize. However what Im trying to achieve is using the service mentioned in another dll running on the same server. I have read autofac but failed (https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html). Thanks for your response.